# How to create custom field and Add more button along with custom field in sugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I want to create a custom field which should have 'Add more button' so that we can add as many as we want..(like email address field with + symbol to add more you can see in Contact Module).Is it possible in SugarCRM studio ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in Studio.

A alternate way to do this, is using relationship. But one-many relationship must be managed with in subpanel.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at using the Collection Field type; it's what's used to power the Email address and Teams fields.